# Can you change timestamp format for history command on tcsh

Tags: shell, command-history, timestamps, tcsh

When I run `history` command (on tcsh), it only prints the TIME portion of the timestamp and omits the date:

```
 3  15:07   echo $PATH
 4  15:07   ls -la
```

In bash, you can use `HISTTIMEFORMAT` environmental variable to affect the timestamp forman printed by `history` command.

E.g. `set HISTTIMEFORMAT="[%F %T %Z] "`

Is there a way to do this in tcsh and if so, which version of tcsh is required? We have tcsh 6.17.00.

Environment: Red Har Linux 4.4, but I assume the answer shouldn't be affected since `history` is a shell built-in and not OS-supplied binary.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

From the `tcsh` man page.

*excerpt*

> history 
>   The  first  word indicates the number of history events to save.  The optional 
>   second word (+) indicates the format in which history is printed; if not 
>   given, `%h\t%T\t%R\n` is used.  The format sequences are described below 
>   under prompt; note the variable meaning of `%R`.  Set to `100` by default.

#### Example

```
$ set history= ( 1000 "%h %W/%D/%Y %T %R\n" )
```

Results in:

```
$ history
     2 09/08/2014 22:48 set history= ( 1000 "%h %W/%D/%Y %T %R\n" )
     7 09/08/2014 22:49 ls
     9 09/08/2014 22:49 echo "hi"
    10 09/08/2014 22:49 history
```

This would result in the history being maintained for the last 1000 commands with the format of `"%h %W/%D/%Y %T %R\n"`.

- `%h` - history #
- `%W/%D/%Y` - month/day/year
- `%T - 24 hr. time
- `%R` - command run

The full descriptions of these macros is defined in the `tcsh` man page, scroll down to the section where the `prompt` command is explained. They're there.

Comment: You have the month & day reversed; you really meant "%W/%D/%Y" for this format:  12/25/2014.  :-)

Comment: And thank you for the answer ... I was really wondering exactly when I had last run some command or other :-)

Seriously. :-)